# Can I execute nuxt asyndata hook on navigation instead of during generate execution?

Tags: nuxt.js

I would like to execute the asyndata hook on normal page navigation (initial page hit). I don't want to execute the asyncdata hook during the generate process. Is this possible in some config setting?

Answer (score 0):

The 'generate' process is only intended for sites that have static content. This means that once they are generated (using the 'npm run generate' command) the content gets fixed.

If you are looking to load your data at the moment that the user loads a page in your site you should not use the 'generate' command, but instead the 'build' command. This will generate a dynamic site that will indeed excecute the asyncData method every time that your user loads a page.

The good news is that you probably don't have to change any of your code. Just stop using:

```
npm run generate
```

And start using

```
npm run build
```

And then you can run the 'npm run start' to init your production server.

(Note: If you are in development, you will only need to run the 'npm run dev' command)